# Microsoft cognitive container Failed to reach endpoint

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to deploy the [MS cognitive container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-container-support?tabs=luis) into a server that has no network enabled but whitelists the required endpoints by Microsoft below:

[image]

However, the container is still not working with error message below:

[image]

I think it means the container still can't reach the endpoint it wants.

Can anybody tell me how to debug it? or tell me the full URL that Microsoft wants to reach so I can test by curl by myself?

**Please note that it seems all outbound traffic actually goes to a proxy first before reaching public internet.**

---

**What I tried so far:**

I tried to curl https://australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com to see if this URL is whitelisted by the server. And it is whitelisted as something returned：

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using HTTP_PROXY and HTTS_PROXY docker run parameter on the MS container to direct the traffic to the proxy directly.